# How do I generate 3d WKT FROM A Sql Server geometry or geography types

Tags: sql-server, well-known-text

If I have the point POINT (-75.45454 25.12345 1024 ) in a geometry or geography column in SQL Server, but render it with `STAsText()` I lose the Z dimension.

> SELECT geography::STGeomFromText('POINT (-75.45454 25.12345 1024 )', 4326).STAsText() AS point
>
> POINT (-75.45454 25.12345)

How do I get the full WKT? There is nothing listed in [OGC Methods on Geography Instances](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933917.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

The answer is [AsTextZM ()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933981.aspx), which is listed on the [Extended Methods on Geography](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933968.aspx).

```
WITH geo AS (
    SELECT geography::STGeomFromText('POINT (-75.45454 25.12345 1024 )', 4326) AS point)
SELECT 
    geo.point.AsTextZM() AS WTKFull,
    geo.point.STAsText() AS WTK2d
FROM geo
```